# How to setup listening port of dropbear under initramfs-tools

Tags: 16.04

This is in reference to: [Ubuntu will not boot into busybox for remote LUKS decryption using dropbear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771362/ubuntu-will-not-boot-into-busybox-for-remote-luks-decryption-using-dropbear/828972#828972)

I have really like this solution by BinaryShrub.

One question: what is the right way to set the listening port of dropbear in this setup?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can specify the options to dropbear in your `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` or `/etc/dropbear/initramfs/dropbear.conf` since Debian 12

`DROPBEAR_OPTIONS="-p 2222"`

And then rebuild the initramfs: `update-initramfs -u`

Comment: Note: `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/config` seems to be the place to do the dropbear specific configs now.

Comment: As I said on https://wiki.debian.org/DropBear the new folder is `/etc/dropbear/initramfs`

Answer (score 4):

I've managed to find a solution (nothing helped me on internet...), I've tried many things as change port in `/etc/default/dropbear` or `etc/init.d/dropbear` without any effect...

So, after searching how initramfs works and how dropbear is launched at boot, here is the solution:

```
$ cd /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount
$ nano dropbear
```

then go to the function `run_dropbear()`, you should find a line with something like this:

```
exec /sbin/dropbear ${DROPBEAR_OPTIONS:-$PKGOPTION_dropbear_OPTION} -Fs
```

Just add the following option at the end of line:

```
exec /sbin/dropbear ${DROPBEAR_OPTIONS:-$PKGOPTION_dropbear_OPTION} -Fs -p #### (where #### is your port number)
```

Don't forget to run `update-initramfs -u` after this modification.
Reboot. Your SSH at boot time should now be on the chosen port.

Cheers

Comment: That is *much* better then your first "answer". 10 points extra!

Comment: Used in [this howto](https://github.com/ceremcem/unlock-luks-partition/blob/master/README.md#run-dropbear-on-additional-ports), thanks.