# Dropbear-initramfs on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: server, 18.04, initramfs

I’m trying to setup a dedicated server with an encrypted drive, I’ve found some help online to get that up and running but I’m running in some troubles getting `dropbear-initramfs` to start properly. (tutorial along those lines https://hamy.io/post/0005/remote-unlocking-of-luks-encrypted-root-in-ubuntu-debian/)

So I install the dropbear-initramfs package and get an error that the keys are missing and it won’t work. I add the authorized_keys I configure dropbear to run on a different port and i update initramfs but at boot dropbear doesn’t start and I just get prompted the normal username/password. I’ve tried a couple of things to get that up and running, I tried to dpkg reconfigure the package once the keys are setup properly and I don’t get an error message anymore but dropbear still doesn’t start.

If anyone has any pointer that would be very appreciated :)

Best regards

P.S: I had a look for the already opened questions but the majority of them are now quite old and the dropbear + initramfs is suppose to be easier since ubuntu 16.04 (with the dropbear-initramfs package).

Comment: Have you tried the update guide https://hamy.io/post/0009/how-to-install-luks-encrypted-ubuntu-18.04.x-server-and-enable-remote-unlocking/ I just tried it on 18.10 and it worked fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *almost* did what what must be done.

###The short version:

###TL;DR
Due to a security issue, the authorized_keys, containing the public key of your client was deleted...

1. Dropbear and openssh are both SSH servers but don't share the same format of  keys, although they share same principle of private-public keys:

- DER format for dropbear
- PEM format for openssh for private keys
- An `authorized_keys` file on the server side,
- A `known_hosts` file on the client side.

That's why to connect to a dropbear server, both `ssh` and `dbclient` can be used, but `/usr/lib/dropbear/dropbearconvert` *must be used* to convert the public keys ensure `ssh` is compatible with dropbear, or to make `dbclient` compatible with `sshd`.

2. Dropbear is much smaller than `sshd` and even though it's more basic, it's good to have an SSH public key-only server available at an early stage of the Linux boot process, specifically when you use a boot loader such as PXE and/or iPXE.
   To do that, dropbear must be integrated to the init filesystem (The `initrd` image).
   The Ubuntu package `dropbear-initramfs` must be installed (I'm using version 2017.75-3build1 on Ubuntu 18.04).
   All dropbear's settings are in the `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/` folder, including the configuration file (`config`), server private keys, rsa, dss, ecdsa (`dropbear_*_host_key`), and client's public keys to accepted (`authorized_keys`) must be placed here in the correct dropbear format.
   Then to update your current `initrd` image file in the `/boot/` directory, you must launch:

   ```
    sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

This package comes with scripts to build `initrd` images in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/dropbear`, and scripts to run in the early stages of the boot process in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/dropbear`, and only then are those last scripts embedded inside the `initrd` images.

3. Some distributions delete `authorized_keys` under certain conditions to prevent `ssh` connections in early stages. To circumvent this, you must check this and workaround such as below:

   ```
    $ cd /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/
    $ grep -R authorized_keys *
    init-bottom/dropbear:# delete authorized_keys(5) file to forbid new SSH sessions
    init-bottom/dropbear:#rm -f ~root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    init-bottom/dropbear:    # just kill this script), so deleting root's authorized_keys(5) file
   ```

In the workaround, we mitigate the deletion of `authorized_keys` to be able to connect into a machine when something goes wrong in the `initramfs` stage.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)**  Looks like an excellent answer (I don't use dropbear, so cannot comment on the validity) but could you please do me a favour and read the [editing help](/editing-help) and have a look at my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1103906/revisions) to improve the readability of your answers in the future, and then [edit] your post and leave a comment below here mentioning @Fabby and I'll come back and upvote.  **;-) 0:-)**

Comment: a shorter short of a short, at the end, true knowledge will end to disappear to make you a guru...
If someone truly want an answer, he must deserve it, than, at least make the effort to read hints...

Comment: Si vous voulez bien rajouter une version plus courte entre **The short version** et **TL;DR**? Not everyone has 30 years of experience like us old farts...  **>:-)**  **+10** already for the long version, +50 for the short version.  leave a comment @Fabby after doing so, please?

Comment: @Fabby: what are you rambling about? :D

Comment: I cqn get into trouble in 10 languages but only out of trouble in 7...  @user643011  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

Works for Debian, should work for Ubuntu too: https://github.com/ceremcem/unlock-luks-partition

## Unlock LUKS Partition with SSH

Below instructions are for booting your SERVER by connecting and unlocking the encrypted partition via your CLIENT over SSH:

**WARNING**: Typing your crypto key over network might be secure (due to the secure nature of the SSH connection) **as long as** you are completely certain that the initramfs has not been subjugated so that there is no MITM attack taking place while you are typing your disk passphrase.

#### 1. Install mandatory packages (on SERVER)

```
apt-get install dropbear initramfs-tools busybox
```

Check that Dropbear has disabled itself in `/etc/default/dropbear`

```
NO_START=1
```

#### 2. Append your desired public keys into the SERVER's authorized_keys file

Just copy and paste your public key(s) into `/etc/dropbear-initramfs/authorized_keys` on SERVER

#### 3. Create the unlock script

Create the following script as `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/crypt_unlock.sh`

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

PREREQ="dropbear"

prereqs() {
  echo "$PREREQ"
}

case "$1" in
  prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
  ;;
esac

. "${CONFDIR}/initramfs.conf"
. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

if [ "${DROPBEAR}" != "n" ] && [ -r "/etc/crypttab" ] ; then
cat > "${DESTDIR}/bin/unlock" << EOF
#!/bin/sh
if PATH=/lib/unlock:/bin:/sbin /scripts/local-top/cryptroot; then
kill \`ps | grep cryptroot | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print \$1}'\`
# following lines will be executed after the passphrase has been correctly entered
# kill the remote shell
kill -9 \`ps | grep "\-sh" | grep -v "grep" | awk '{print \$1}'\`
exit 0
fi
exit 1
EOF

  chmod 755 "${DESTDIR}/bin/unlock"

  mkdir -p "${DESTDIR}/lib/unlock"
cat > "${DESTDIR}/lib/unlock/plymouth" << EOF
#!/bin/sh
[ "\$1" == "--ping" ] && exit 1
/bin/plymouth "\$@"
EOF

  chmod 755 "${DESTDIR}/lib/unlock/plymouth"

  echo To unlock root-partition run "unlock" >> ${DESTDIR}/etc/motd

fi
```

Make it executable:

```bsh
chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/hooks/crypt_unlock.sh
```

Create the cleanup script as `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/cleanup.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
echo "Killing dropbear"
killall dropbear
exit 0
```

...and make it executable:

```bsh
chmod +x /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/cleanup.sh
```

#### 4. Create a static IP (or skip this step to use DHCP)

Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf` to add (or change) the line:

```
IP=192.168.1.254::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0::eth0:off
```

```
format: 

    IP=${ip}::${gateway_ip}:${netmask}:[${hostname}]:${eth_device}:${autoconf}

([hostname] can be omitted)
```

> In newer kernels `eth0` is renamed to `enp0s3` (or something like that). Check that out with `ls /sys/class/net`

#### 5. Update initramfs

**WARNING**: Be careful if you **directly** edited `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, since it will be **overwritten** by below command. You may end up with a broken boot sequence. See [the important note](https://github.com/ceremcem/smith-sync/blob/master/doc/create-bootable-backup.md#important).

```
update-initramfs -u
```

#### 6. Test

1. Reboot your server
2. Connect to your server via `ssh root@192.168.1.254 [-i ~/.ssh/id_rsa]`

## Advanced configuration

#### Create a Reverse Tunnel

You may want your SERVER to connect your Link Up Server with SSH, create a reverse tunnel to its SSH Server, so you can connect your SERVER over your Link Up Server, which eliminates the need for firewall forwarding for above process.

(see reverse-tunnel-setup.md)

#### Run Dropbear on additional ports

(based on https://askubuntu.com/a/840067/371730)

1. Define extra ports:

   ```
   --- /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/dropbear   2018-09-22 01:55:50.963967412 +0300
   +++ /usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-premount/dropbear   2018-09-22 01:56:04.091945164 +0300
   @@ -26,7 +26,7 @@
   -    exec /sbin/dropbear $DROPBEAR_OPTIONS -Fs
   +    exec /sbin/dropbear $DROPBEAR_OPTIONS -Fs -p 22 -p 80
   ```
2. Update initramfs:

   ```
   update-initramfs -u
   ```